# Undocumented $references$ replacement token

Tags: .net, deployment, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

According to NuGet's Nuspec documentation, I should be able to use the `$references$` replacement token to override the convention of referencing everything in the \lib folder.

> $references$
>
> This element contains a set of  elements, each of which
>   specifies an assembly that will be referenced by the project. The
>   existence of this element overrides the convention of pulling
>   everything in the lib folder. More info below.

Source: http://docs.nuget.org/create/nuspec-reference#replacement-tokens

Can someone give an example of how this token is actually used?